# Rendering React List Items One after the other after a specific period of time

Tags: reactjs, native

I'm new to React...and I'm trying to render a list of times with each item coming after the last item rendered after like 10 seconds...How can this be made possible...

Comment: Think about it from ```state``` perspective, add elements to an ```array``` with a 10 seconds delay, and map over all the items in ```array``` in the render function

Comment: You update the state by inserting stuff to it after some delay. For the web you would use `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`

Comment: I'm asking how do you do what you've described .... I'm still new to React and React Native